# Height Difference between characters while displaying using font file

Tags: fonts, font-size, truetype, text-rendering, fontforge

I have done ligature substitution with the help of [this doc](https://fontforge.org/docs/tutorial/editexample4.html). Once done, I have reduced the height Element > Transformations > Glyph Origin > Scale Uniformily ... [with for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sb2W.png)

Finally I have generated the font file. Using that I have rendered in HTML, there is a height difference in the characters of the font example1: [size 10pt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nHCP.png) but for [size 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpxxC.png) pt it is properly displaying, similarly example2: [size 10pt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYEpm.png) also [size 14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LxUR.png) pt I can see difference.

How to fix this?

I have tried by changing the emsizes. I think the issue might be in kerning.